# HTML Select tag too big

Tags: javascript, html

I basically have this hard-coded:-

```html
<select id="nr">   
                 <option value="0">0</option>
                 <option value="1">1</option>
                 <option value="2">2</option>
                 <option value="3">3</option>
                 <option value="4">4</option>
                 <option value="5">5</option>
               </select>
```

It is supposed to select a value from an array, is there a way I can make a select without hard coding all those values? Preferably creating one with a loop with the length of my array in javascript or html?

Comment: What's the point of this? Can't you just make a number input? This is kind of... bad practice?

Comment: @JoshuaBakker It's a silly assignment my teacher asked me to do and I've got no idea how. He basically wants to limit users from selecting an index that doesn't exist in an array, but he also wants to give them the possibility to select an index that exists in the array.

Comment: Well I don't know why he would tell you to do that, having a select with option with values and display as just numbers is kind of useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps you!

```js
function addOptionValue(value) {
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  option.setAttribute('value', value);
  option.innerHTML = value;
  selectEl.appendChild(option);
}

var optionsArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
selectEl = document.getElementById('nr');

for (i in optionsArray) {
  addOptionValue(optionsArray[i]);
}
```

```html
<select id="nr"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery

```
$(function(){
    for (i=1;i<=5;i++){
        $("#nr").append($('<option></option>').val(i).html(i))
    }
});
```

Javascript

```
<script>
for(var i=1; i<=5; i++){
   var option = document.createElement("option");
   option.value = i;
   option.text = i;
   document.getElementById('nr').appendChild(option);
}
/<script>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vaaocd4v/)

Comment: Is it possible to do something similar in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```js
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
var select_elem = document.getElementById("nr");
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = arr[i];
    option.text = arr[i];
    select_elem.appendChild(option)
}
```

```html
<select id="nr">       
</select>
```

Comment: That's what i'm looking for but could you supply the entire file because I tried implementating that but it didnt work for me :p

Comment: what do you mean by "the entire file"? The code works in the code snippet

Comment: Jquery seems by far the easiest way to do this    
  `$(function(){
    var $select = $(".1-100");
    for (i=1;i<=100;i++){
        $select.append($('<option></option>').val(i).html(i))
    }
});​`